# GLSL version error with any version OS X

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am trying to run an SDL2 application and it has shaders written in GLSL. When the shaders are compiled I get this message -> error version '130' is not supported.

I am on OS X 10.10, I have tried setting the the shaders to a different shader model version but with no luck.

Does anyone know anything that could cause this? The program runs but I get a black screen, I can hear the sound and I get the FPS output to a console.

Comment: Make sure that you're requesting an OpenGL 3.0 or higher context from SDL. The default context version is 2.1 in OS X 10.10.

Comment: I'm getting v3.3 unfortunately.

Comment: OSX supports GLSL 1.10 and 1.20 in legacy profiles, and GLSL >= 1.50 in core profiles.

Comment: Sorry should have noted I'm using glew wrapper.

Comment: GLEW is unnecessary on Mac OS. It will probably cause you more problems than it solves.

Comment: It's not my choice unfortunately, it's an open source project.